# Meteor, LESS, and Bootstrap (Bootswatch)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less

So, I'm trying to author a small Meteor package that includes the LESS version of Bootstrap, along with my favorite Bootswatch theme.  I'm apparently doing something wrong, because when I try to even use the normal Bootstrap grid system, nothing happens.

**package.js**

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "Bootstrap 3, using Sandstone Bootswatch.  (LESS version)",
    version: "3.2.0",
    git: "https://github.com/czbaker/meteor-bootstrap-3-sandstone"
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {

    // For Meteor 0.9.1.1
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.1.1');

    // Dependencies
    api.use('less', 'client');
    api.use('jquery', 'client');

    // Bootstrap's Javascript Stuff
    api.add_files('lib/js/transition.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/alert.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/button.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/carousel.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/collapse.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/dropdown.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/modal.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/tooltip.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/popover.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/scrollspy.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/tab.js', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/js/affix.js', 'client');

    // Fonts
    api.add_files('lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf', 'client');
    api.add_files('lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', 'client');

});
```

This is loosely based on a pre-0.9 package, and will deal with (hopefully) providing the JavaScript stuff in Bootstrap.  My problem is currently with the LESS files.  Here's a tree of my Package:

```
misutowolf@jakiro ~/projects/bootstrap-3-sandstone-less $ tree
.
├── lib
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── affix.js
│   │   ├── alert.js
│   │   ├── button.js
│   │   ├── carousel.js
│   │   ├── collapse.js
│   │   ├── dropdown.js
│   │   ├── modal.js
│   │   ├── popover.js
│   │   ├── scrollspy.js
│   │   ├── tab.js
│   │   ├── tooltip.js
│   │   └── transition.js
│   └── less
│       ├── alerts.import.less
│       ├── badges.import.less
│       ├── bootstrap.import.less
│       ├── bootswatch.import.less
│       ├── breadcrumbs.import.less
│       ├── button-groups.import.less
│       ├── buttons.import.less
│       ├── carousel.import.less
│       ├── close.import.less
│       ├── code.import.less
│       ├── component-animations.import.less
│       ├── dropdowns.import.less
│       ├── forms.import.less
│       ├── glyphicons.import.less
│       ├── grid.import.less
│       ├── input-groups.import.less
│       ├── jumbotron.import.less
│       ├── labels.import.less
│       ├── list-group.import.less
│       ├── media.import.less
│       ├── mixins
│       │   ├── alerts.import.less
│       │   ├── background-variant.import.less
│       │   ├── border-radius.import.less
│       │   ├── buttons.import.less
│       │   ├── center-block.import.less
│       │   ├── clearfix.import.less
│       │   ├── forms.import.less
│       │   ├── gradients.import.less
│       │   ├── grid-framework.import.less
│       │   ├── grid.import.less
│       │   ├── hide-text.import.less
│       │   ├── image.import.less
│       │   ├── labels.import.less
│       │   ├── list-group.import.less
│       │   ├── nav-divider.import.less
│       │   ├── nav-vertical-align.import.less
│       │   ├── opacity.import.less
│       │   ├── pagination.import.less
│       │   ├── panels.import.less
│       │   ├── progress-bar.import.less
│       │   ├── reset-filter.import.less
│       │   ├── resize.import.less
│       │   ├── responsive-visibility.import.less
│       │   ├── size.import.less
│       │   ├── tab-focus.import.less
│       │   ├── table-row.import.less
│       │   ├── text-emphasis.import.less
│       │   ├── text-overflow.import.less
│       │   └── vendor-prefixes.import.less
│       ├── mixins.import.less
│       ├── modals.import.less
│       ├── navbar.import.less
│       ├── navs.import.less
│       ├── normalize.import.less
│       ├── pager.import.less
│       ├── pagination.import.less
│       ├── panels.import.less
│       ├── popovers.import.less
│       ├── print.import.less
│       ├── progress-bars.import.less
│       ├── responsive-embed.import.less
│       ├── responsive-utilities.import.less
│       ├── scaffolding.import.less
│       ├── tables.import.less
│       ├── theme.import.less
│       ├── thumbnails.import.less
│       ├── tooltip.import.less
│       ├── type.import.less
│       ├── utilities.import.less
│       ├── variables.import.less
│       └── wells.import.less
├── package.js
└── versions.json
```

So, I understand that in order to get Meteor to not process LESS files, they must be named `<file>.import.less`, and that's fine.  What I don't understand is where to go from here.

In my project (testing), I assumed that I would need to write a main `.less` file, which would import the main `bootstrap.import.less` from my package, but I don't know where it's located, so to speak.  Pre-0.9, this would have been in `/packages/<package>/lib/less/bootstrap.import.less`, or something like that.

What am I missing here?  I thought also if I just dropped the `.import` from the main bootstrap "container", that it would just get included as part of the package, and provide it to my app, but that's not the case either.  If that were so, would I just do that, and then use `api.add_files('lib/less/bootstrap.less');` to provide it to the client?

Comment: So, it seems that I guess I should have tried my last suggestion before posting this question. After dropping the `.import` from the 'container' Bootstrap .less file, and using `api.add_files` with it, it seems to be working, at least now my test document has style associated with it.  I still can't use Bootstrap's mixins in a custom .less file, though.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a `.less` file in a package with `api.add_files`, what actually happens when then package is strapped is, it gets converted to a `.less.css` file. So there are no mixins available for you to use. Additionally, if there was a real `.less` file to be used, you would need to `@import` it in the file where you want to use the mixins/variables.

There is a hack. You could add the files as an asset to the server.

```
api.add_files([
  "lib/less/variables.less",
  "lib/less/mixins.less"
  ... add all the mixins .less files here too...
], "server", {
  isAsset: true
})
```

You will need to add all the less files in the /mixins folder here too, since those are imported with an relative path in `mixins.less`.

You're able to `@import` the variables/mixins then in your own `.less` files, with this quirky path:

```
@bootstrap-path: ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/{your_user_name}_{your_package_name}/lib/less";
@import "@{bootstrap-path}/mixins.less";
```

Replace the `{your_user_name}_{your_package_name}` with the name under which you publish your package. `user:package` will get to `user_package`.

But remember, that the Bootstrap less code which is sent to the client already got converted to css, so there is no way to change the variables or mixins to adjust the Bootstrap settings.